# Describing convergence/divergence of a complex sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let (a$_n$)$_{n \in N}$  be a complex sequence and a $\in$ C. Show that the following statements are equivalent:

1. $\forall$ $\varepsilon$ > 0 $\exists$ N $\in$ **N** $\forall$ n $\geq$ N : |a$_n$ - a| < $\varepsilon$
2. $\forall$ $\delta$ > 0 $\exists$ M $\in$ **N** $\forall$ n $\geq$ M : |a$_n$ - a| $\leq$ $\delta$
3. $\forall$ $\lambda$ > 0 $\exists$ K $\in$ **N** $\forall$ n $\geq$ K : |a$_n$ - a| $\leq$ 64$\lambda$$^2$

I am a bit confused about this one. I know that 1. implies that the limit of a$_n$ is a, but is this true for 2. and 3.? Notice that in 2., |a$_n$ - a| is less than or equal to delta, which is throwing me off.

Comment: Use $\delta= \epsilon/2$ in (2), and note that $A\leq \epsilon/2 \implies A<\epsilon$ if $\epsilon$ is positive (not zero).

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$\left|a-a_n\right|<\varepsilon$$

Implies:

$$\left|a-a_n\right| \leq \varepsilon$$

On the other hand:

$$\left|a-a_n\right| \leq \varepsilon$$

Implies:

$$\left|a-a_n\right| < 2\varepsilon$$